# How to edit table content on clicking edit button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a table using javascript , now i want to edit each row when i tap on edit button in the end of the row 
Here is my code to create a dynamic table

```
function addRow() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = firstname.value;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = lastname.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">' + '<input type="button" value = "Edit" onClick="Javacsript:editRow(this)">';
```

Once user clicks on edit button table cells should become editable once each cell is edited it should change the value.

Comment: You haven't copied the entire function content.

Comment: could you make jsFiddle for what you have done yet?

Comment: Can we see the html?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ppfs9y2/

Comment: where is javascript code in fiddle?

Comment: I have updated a new link in the comment please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using jQuery. This will require several steps:

1. Make row editable on buttonclick with:

   ```
   $("yourcell").contentEditable = true;
   ```
2. Create a hook on change:

   ```
   $("yourcell").change(function(){
       //do a server update
   });
   ```
3. Post new data on server with jQuery post:

   ```
   $.post( "insertyourdata.php", function( data ) {
        //let user know the save has been done
   });
   ```

If you want to edit whole row, you can create a class for each row like row142 and then select the cells by this class.

Comment: It has 4 cells in a row , say like name , age , address and street , if user wants to edit the entire row i have provided him a edit option at end of the row , clicking on edit button all this 4 cells become editable , once user edits and click on any part of the page all the cells become disabled or locked and saves the new value in it , this is what i am trying to achieve